# Java Optimize Unsigned N-Bit Integer Object

Tags: java, optimization, wrapper, bit-manipulation, unsigned-integer

I am in the process of writing my own Integer Wrapper class that extends Number. I believe that I have most the functionality implemented. At the moment I am using bit-level operations.

**Questions**

1. Am I doing anything that could pose a problem or conflicts with the `Number` class?
2. I noticed that `Number` creates an immutable integer under the covers, but I want to be able to manipulate my underlying integer. Is this a bad idea?
3. How should I handle negatives integers? I need this to be an unsigned-integer, so I will only be able to store up to 31 bits reliably. Can I store all 32 and treat it as an unsigned or will I have to use a `long` as my `value` under the covers?
4. Should I throw an error if the user passes a negative number to the constructor or should I just set the value to zero?

   `this.value = value > 0 ? extractLowerBits(value) : 0;`

Here is my Integer Wrapper:

**NBitUInteger.java**

```
public final class NBitUInteger extends Number implements
        Comparable<NBitUInteger> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int value;
    private final int bits;
    private final int bitMask;

    public static final int MIN_VALUE = 0x0;
    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;

    public NBitUInteger() {
        this(0);
    }

    public NBitUInteger(int value) {
        this(value, 32);
    }

    public NBitUInteger(int value, int bits) {
        this.bits = bits;
        this.bitMask = bitMask(bits);
        this.value = extractLowerBits(value);
    }

    private final int extractLowerBits(final int value) {
        return value & bitMask;
    }

    public int bitMask() {
        return this.bitMask;
    }

    public int bits() {
        return this.bits;
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return (long) this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return (float) this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return (double) this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NBitUInteger other) {
        return compare(this.value, other.value);
    }

    public static final int compare(final int x, final int y) {
        return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public final NBitUInteger shiftRight(final int amount) {
        this.value = this.value >> amount;

        return this;
    }

    public final NBitUInteger shiftRight() {
        return shiftRight(1);
    }

    public final NBitUInteger shiftRightPrependBit(final int bit) {
        this.value = (bit << (bits - 1)) | shiftRight().intValue();

        return this;
    }

    public final NBitUInteger shiftLeft(final int amount) {
        this.value = (this.value << amount) & bitMask;

        return this;
    }

    public final NBitUInteger shiftLeft() {
        return shiftLeft(1);
    }

    public final NBitUInteger shiftLeftAppendBit(final int bit) {
        this.value = shiftLeft().intValue() | bit;

        return this;
    }

    public final String toBinaryString() {
        return toBinaryString(this.value, this.bits);
    }

    public static final String toBinaryString(int value, int bits) {
        StringBuilder binStr = new StringBuilder(Integer.toBinaryString(value));

        while (binStr.length() < bits)
            binStr.insert(0, '0');

        return binStr.toString();
    }

    public static final int bitMask(final int bits) {
        return (1 << bits) - 1;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public class NBitUIntegerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NBitUInteger x = new NBitUInteger(13, 4);
        printResult(x, 13);

        x.shiftRight().shiftRight().shiftRight();
        printResult(x, 1);

        x.shiftLeft(2);
        printResult(x, 4);

        x.shiftLeftAppendBit(1).shiftLeftAppendBit(1).shiftLeftAppendBit(1);
        printResult(x, 7);

        x.shiftRightPrependBit(1);
        printResult(x, 11);
    }

    public static void printResult(NBitUInteger value, int expected) {
        System.out.printf("%s == %s => %b\n",
            value.toBinaryString(),
            NBitUInteger.toBinaryString(expected, value.bits()),
            (value.intValue() == expected));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1101 == 1101 => true
0001 == 0001 => true
0100 == 0100 => true
0111 == 0111 => true
1011 == 1011 => true
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for questions like this.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Sorry, its late and I have been up for 20 hours and will get up again in 4. I had left a few details out because I am distracted...

Comment: Dude get some sleep, this can wait :-)

Comment: I cleaned up my original question. Should I keep this post here or should I move it over to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?